In the game "Content Warning", can being loud over voice chat annoy viewers and lower engagement?
I'm playing Content Warning, a game that mimics being a "content creator" or a "YouTuber".
Being a scary game (and susceptible to jump scares), it's not uncommon to yell out loud (as in me in real life, not the video game character you play as), which in turn gets captured over the audio for the video you film. I've noticed that users will sometimes comment, "<UserName> is so loud". I assume this means that if you are consistently making a loud sound (i.e., shrieking in terror), it will annoy your viewers.
In Content Warning, does being loud over voice chat deter engagement of your viewers on your videos?

Is this is a question about game streaming engagement?

@Neon1024 no... the game mimics being a "content creator" - a "YouTuber" essentially.  What I am talking about is in-game mechanics only, not IRL engagement with the game on Twitch or other streaming platforms with real content creators.  I updated the tag wiki to explain some of the gameplay.

I've edited the title of the question to specify that you're talking about the game Content Warning because otherwise it's impossible to know what you're talking about, and anybody would think you're talking about real viewers on Twitch. I hope the edit gets approved because it's really needed here. Otherwise you can edit the title yourself, OP, like "In the game Content Warning, can being loud...." @TimmyJim

I'm glad I wasn't the only one who fell for this

As far as I can tell being loud does nothing asides the viewer's icon looks like annoyed a bit. We (4-man friends squad) were being as loud as jet engine, but still made 2.1k views in the first day of the career (which needs 3k total view in 3 days to progress to next 3 days). I'm not completely sure if it affects the engagement, hence comment. P.S. being calm also makes viewers to comment (like %username%'s voice is soothing or something like that), but that also does nothing, it seems.
